# php send http request by client

Tags: php, http, request, send

I have a php page thats coded similiar to this code (show.php) :

`<?php echo (isset($_POST['form']))?($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];):('not sent') ?>`
and I have a page (send.php) that send data to show.php using curl

when user request the show.php , server show server's ip , but I want to show user's IP , I don't want to send data by HTML , can I use php to solve this problem ?!

thank you .

Comment: if user didn't request the php page, it will never know his IP. You are sending data by curl so the user is server. If real user has requested the page that makes curl request, you can get user's IP there and send it to show.php in POST params.

Comment: Tnq Andrei , but see you whene we redirect a user to show.php by header php function , show.php show his ip ?! isn't here any way to redirect user that have any post params ?!

Comment: Header redirect just tells the browser to request different address, the browser still has user IP, but when you send POST with another PHP script (not the browser) it is sent from the server and user environment is lost. If you need user IP, add it to the POST.

Comment: tnq Andrei , but I want to get a method to forced the user to post params by him self , isn't here any way ?!

Comment: can you please edit your question and give a precise description step by step: 1) what is the initial web page which we see in browser 2) what user does on this page 3) what does the script that receives data sent by user 4) what other script does 5) etc.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko , thank you for your reply , it's about a private webserver's vulnerability and I can't tell you more about it , I'm sorry but this page is public and this bug is private so I can't .... , if you wan't to know , we can have a private disscusion. so if you want you can tell me for get my contact details , ;)

Comment: No, I don't mean webpage address etc. Just the general description like this: "1) A webpage has user form 2) User sends POST data from this page to next page 3) The next page does something and sends data to other page etc."

Answer (score 0):

You can add the users IP address to the POST variables that get sent when accessing the send.php page using curl.

depending on your code there are different methods to accomplish this.

Comment: tnq JEL3 , please see previus conversions !